# Регулярные выражения. Распарсить вложенный объект с фигурными скобками

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как правильно написать регулярное выражение что бы из такой коллекции можно было вытянуть определенный объект?

Пример:

```
{
    name: "object 1",
    items: [
        {
            name: "object 2",
            need: true,
            items: [
                {
                    name: "sub_object 1"
                },
                {
                    name: "sub_object 2",
                    need: true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "object 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Задача: Как вытащить вложенный объект с свойством need: true

Моя реализация:

```
|(?:\{(?:(?!{).)*need: true(?:(?!{).)*\}?)|s
```

!Вопрос является переформулированным, потому как я получаю ответы не решающие мою проблему, и видимо вводит сообщество в заблуждение относительно JSON.

Comment: Если данные выглядят как JSON, то и парсить их надо как JSON. Если нет - надо чётко представлять их структуру и писать парсер для неё :) Потому как замучаетесь писать регулярки, "находящие" такие объекты: `foo : "bar=need: true"`, и много чего другого левого.

Answer (score 1):

JSON парсится намного проще

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

теперь `obj` это обычный javascript объект, и можно по нему провести поиск через циклы, или рекурсивную функцию (для древовидной структуры).

Например что бы получить items используем `obj["items"]`.

Comment: Увы но это не JSON, а объект в JS.
Проблема в том что я не могу использовать V8, и написать на нём простенький парсер с рекурсией

Comment: @Дмитрий а в чём разница JSON и объекта в JS? Вообщем-то ваша задача как я понимаю вообще не решается регуляторным выражением, так как объект может содержать в себе любое количество подобъектов, а регуляторные выражения как я знаю не работают с рекурсий. Хотя я слышал что новые версии регуляторных выражения на perl умеют работать, и некоторые расширения, но не знаю работает ли это в javascript. Возможно тогда через регуляторку находить начало объекта но вытаскивать как-то по-другому. И всё-же что мешает использовать JSON.parse?

Comment: @Дмитрий кстати если вы не можете использовать новые версии javascript, то посмотрите в сторону компилируемого javascript такого как babel или typescript.